# How can I create a Spotlight in a Vertex Shader?

Tags: 3d, graphics, lighting, hlsl

```
Texture2D texture1;
SamplerState Sampler;

struct PixelShaderInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float2 UV : UV;
    float4 World_pos : World_pos;
       
};

struct S_L //Spotlight
{
    float3 pos;     // Position of the spotlight
    float range;    // Range of the spotlight
    float3 dir;     // Direction of the spotlight
    float cone;     // Cone angle of the spotlight
    float3 att;     // Attenuation of the spotlight (constant, linear, quadratic)
    float pad2;     // Padding for alignment
    float4 ambient; // Ambient color of the spotlight
    float4 diffuse; // Diffuse color of the spotlight
};

float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    S_L LIGHT;
    float4(abs(input.normal), 1.0f);
    float4 sampling = texture1.Sample(Sampler, input.UV);
    return sampling;
    
}
```

Comment: What does this code do? How do current results differ from what you expect? In fact, what implementation details are you focusing on?

Comment: i think i have figure it out. i need to implement a light source.